# Constructing Kotlin classes for using Gson to convert json response to class

Tags: android, json, rest, kotlin

I am beginning to learn Android development, and at the moment I am focusing on how to consume REST API's. The service that I am experimenting with (The Movie Database) provides a response of the form:

```
{
    "certifications": {
        "CA": [
            {
                "certification": "G",
                "meaning": "All ages.",
                "order": 1
            },
            ...
        ],
        "NL": [
            {
                "certification": "AL",
                "meaning": "All ages.",
                "order": 1
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

There are quite a long list of objects contained in the list (CA, NL, EN, etc.) but all of these objects contain the same thing - a list of objects of the exact same structure. Any of the online JSON to Kotlin class converters that I have tried want to create individual classes for each object which to me seems wasteful.

I currently have this class:

```
class Certifications {
    var certifications: List<Country>? = null
}

class Country {
    var country: String? = null
    var ratings: List<Certification>? = null
}

class Certification {
    var certification: String? = null
    var meaning: String? = null
    var order: Int = 0
}
```

Attempting this `val thing = gson.fromJson(body, Certifications::class.java)` results in  `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 20 path $.certifications`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This :

```
class Certifications {
    var certifications: List<Country>? = null
}
```

Should be something like :

```
class Certifications {
    var certifications: Map<String, <List<Certification>>? = null
}
```

Where the `String` is the code `"NL"` & `"CA"` - or if you already have a custom type adapter you could do `Map<Country, <List<Certification>>` - but I'm unsure if you have this setup.